# Cannot read file from cloud storage

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

Code to read file

```
boolean lockForRead = false;
String filename = "/gs/smsspamfilteraptosin/Data";
AppEngineFile readableFile = new AppEngineFile(filename);
FileReadChannel readChannel = fileService.openReadChannel(readableFile, lockForRead);


BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(Channels.newReader(readChannel, "UTF")); => I think something went wrong here.I put a string test and after this line the string test was  null.
String line = reader.readLine();
```

Path in cloud storage

```
smsspamfilteraptosin/Data
```

ACL Permission for app

```
FULL_CONTROL
```

When I tried printing out line, the result was null.

And this is what I saw in the admin log : API serving not allowed for this application

Can somebody tell me what I did incorrectly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting the same "API serving not allowed for this application" error when I try to follow the tutorial at: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v9TG7OzsZqQ

My Cloud Endpoint REST API works well on my local development machine, but is not visible when
when I deploy to App Engine.

Is it possible that this "API serving not allowed for this application" is the result of a dependency on a paid feature that we don't have enabled?

Update: Check [GAE: API serving not allowed for this application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11565699/gae-api-serving-not-allowed-for-this-application) for a (partial?) solution.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't do something listed in the [prerequisites](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlestorage/overview#Prerequisites), and this is preventing you from using GCS from app engine.