# GAE: API serving not allowed for this application

Tags: google-app-engine

I am attempting to follow the tutorial at: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v9TG7OzsZqQ

My Cloud Endpoint REST API works well on my local development machine, but when I deploy to App Engine, I receive errors in my Admin Log that "API serving not allowed for this application".

Is this a paid feature that I must enable billing to receive? If not, is there documentation that explains this issue and how to fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use Endpoints in production you need to be accepted into the trusted tester program. You can apply [here](http://endpoints-trusted-tester.appspot.com). Mention this Stack Overflow post in your request and I'll see if I can expedite approval.