# Hello world app - API serving not allowed for this application

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets

So, all I'm doing is creating a default Google App Engine (GAE) project which prints "Hello World" and deploying it to the server. I keep getting the following error message:

```
Error: Server Error
The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.

If the problem persists, please report your problem and mention this error message and
the query that caused it.
```

And the admin logs shows the following:

```
API serving not allowed for this application
```

I haven't done anything at the moment, it's just the default `Servlet`. It works fine on my laptop using `Debug as -> Web application`

I tried changing the JVM to 1.6 and also setting the compliance level to 1.6, but keep getting the same error message.

EDIT: I was looking under `Administration->Admin Logs` so far, but when I looked under `Main->Logs`, I found the actual exception being thrown. Looks like an issue with the JVM version I'm using:

```
Uncaught exception from servlet
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: testwebproject/TestWebProjectServlet : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-5f33a9433a8c2a4e(Request.java)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:91)
at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:71)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:73)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:242)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:454)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:461)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:703)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:338)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:330)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:458)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

Comment: Did you enable Cloud Endpoints?

Comment: Isnt' that required if you're building a REST or SOAP service? But to answer your question, no I didn't. I did read that it could take a few weeks to get approval for it though.

Comment: You should only enable that if you build Cloud Endpoint enabled app: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11565699/gae-api-serving-not-allowed-for-this-application

Comment: Afaik, this error can happen if you use any of the "tester" APIs that Google needs to enable case-by-case, like Cloud Endpoints.

Comment: @Peter - Yes, saw that link earlier. It's weird that the I'm facing this error. Maybe it's something to do with my app engine account? I'm just using the standard project, without typing a single line of code.

Comment: Looks like I found the actual exception being thrown, was looking under `Administratoin->Admin Logs` whereas the actual problem was displayed under `Main->Logs`

Updated the question. Looks like it's an issue with the version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay it works now. The first problem was that I was looking at the wrong place for the logs. The second problem was because of the JVM version I was using. I made sure that the version used is the in the following areas:

1. Project->Properties->Java Build Path->Libraries
2. Project->Properties->Java Compiler
3. Window->Preferences->Java->Installed JREs

I'm using JDK 1.7.0_05

EDIT: Big thanks to Peter Knego for the helpful comments